# Monotouch and XCode 4, where did the outlets go?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Today I updated my mac with the latest version of MonoDevelop, MonoTouch and the Mono-Framework. I also downloaded the latest version of XCode, version 4 (a nifty 4.5 gig download).

At first I did not notice it because I was busy copying code into my project for re-use. But when the time came to actually add some controls, actions and outlets to the MainWindow file - I realized that something was missing.

Hopefully I have over-looked something, because I cannot find functions for adding outlets and actions any more? After googling the problem I realized that the new XCode now does these things by code -- but not in C#, it's exclusively an Objective C thing.

How exactly do I solve this problem? I am currently downloading XCode 3.2.6 but surely there has to be a better option? (I dont even know if this will install over the 4.x version) How exactly do I define actions and outlets by code? Are there any tutorials on this to curve the extra time it will take?

Any help is welcome

**Update:** A tip for those who need to remove XCode and start from scratch. Open a terminal window and type:

```
"sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all"
```

This will remove your current XCode installation (all of it). Remember to re-boot your Mac afterwards. You can then install an older version of XCode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Miguel's [MT 4.0 Announcement](http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2011/Apr-06.html)

> We are currently hard at work to add
>   support to MonoDevelop to work with
>   the new XCode 4.
>
> With XCode 4, Apple removed Interface
>   Builder as a standalone tool. We
>   should have a beta in a couple of
>   weeks of the solution we came up with.

Comment: Ok. Do you know if the 3.2.6 version will install over xcode 4? If so I can use that until the problem is fixed. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I think you can install them side-by-side.

Comment: AFAIK you can install 3.2.6 over 4.0. However, another way is to install Xcode 3.2.6 to /Xcode3 or something, then set /Xcode3/Applications/Interface Builder.app as the default handler for xib files.

Answer (score 1):

you can install them side by side by doing so(I believe you have Xcode 4 installed):
Run the Xcode 3 installer 
When you can choose the install location change it to the folder of your choice but not to developer
Complete the installation and open Xcode 3
done

Answer (score -2):

use mono for mac os.

then convert your application on monomac solution and build and run application, after build u get .app file,

for this you need C# plugin on mono.

or cocoa sharp plugin.

Comment: Please add some reference or some example.