# Monotouch with Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, xamarin.ios

I know this was asked previously when Xcode 4 was still in pre-release stage, but now that it is out... Does anyone know how to add outlets and connections with Xcode 4 and Monotouch?  The Monotouch trial I downloaded says it requires iPhone SDK 4.3, so it must support it.

Or is there still a way to use Monotouch with Xcode 3?

Thanks.

Comment: I was having trouble figuring this one out myself. +1

Comment: iOS SDK4.3 also is available with Xcode 3.2.6

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636088/monotouch-and-xcode-4-where-did-the-outlets-go/5636348#5636348

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you refer to Interface Builder. If so, just stick with Xcode 3, where IB is still separate.
If you log in to Apple's site at http://developer.apple.com, there is a link where you can download Xcode 4. Below it, you can see "Looking for Xcode 3? Download". There, you can download Xcode 3 together with the 4.3 SDK. The direct link is: http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20792

Comment: Thanks!  So is it certain as of now that we can't use Xcode 4 with Monotouch?

Comment: What would you need except IB? I'm still waiting for someone to write an alternative interface editor as I don't like IB too much.

Comment: Mainly just wondering what happens when they discontinue Xcode 3 with the later SDK releases...

Comment: Nothing. You just need the SDK, so install Xcode 4 and you have it. Life is fine without Interface Builder but I'm sure somebody from the MT team will come up with a solution if necessary, they are pretty smart guys :-)